# What moisture barrier would I use in this specific situation in a basement bathroom for a shower?

Tags: plumbing, shower, plumbing-fixture, vapor-barrier

I live in climate zone 4.
It's hot in the summer cold in the winter.
It can get pretty humid since we live near rivers.
This is an exterior wall.

The shower will touch the two studs that are attached to cinder block and then touch the other stud that is sticking out. All the lumber is pressure treated. The part of the wall with faced batts has a thin silver insulation layer behind the batts and then wooden exterior paneling (no cinder blocks). I was planning on spray foam insulating the gap between the two studs touching the cinder block but haven't yet.

What in do I do about a moisture barrier? Manufacturer recommends one for the exterior wall only. Online says that if I put one the vapor will come in during the summer and condense against the barrier and the water will be trapped in the wall and mold.

Currently I'm leaning towards a vapor retardant or something similar but

1. I'm not sure if that's right, and
2. I can find 10 articles talking about the best perm rating for different situations but I can't find a single product that actually lists any perm rating.

I've been going in circles for an hour.

[image: image description here]